# Avoid restarting for-loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, restart

I have a folder with pictures. For each picture, I want to take the maximum value and add it to a new matrix (I created a zeros-matrix, so the zeroes will be replaced with the new values).

This is my code:

```
function handles = original(hObject, eventdata, handles)

handles.weed=handles.selected;
pic=imread(handles.me);
handles.pic=pic;
axes(handles.axes1)
imshow(pic);
num=max(pic(:))
zeroMat = zeros(1,70);
handles.zeroMat = zeroMat;

for i =1:3
    if zeroMat(1,i)~= 0;
        i=i+1
    else
        zeroMat(1,i)=num
        break
    end
end

zeroMat(1,i)=num
```

Every time I select a new picture, the `zeromat` restarts itself to a new zeros-matrix. I know why it happens, but unfortunately I don't know how to overcome it.

This is the output:

pic1:

```
zeroMat =

  Columns 1 through 20

   255     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

  Columns 21 through 40

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

  Columns 41 through 60

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

  Columns 61 through 70

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

pic2:

```
  Columns 1 through 20

   203     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

  Columns 21 through 40

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

  Columns 41 through 60

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

  Columns 61 through 70

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: You should edit the question with your correction. Also, you probably don't want to use the line `i = i+1` within your `for i = 1:3` loop

Comment: @Steve why not ? if it is not zero i want to skip to the next index 
the problem is with this that the matrix is going back to a zero mat after the foor loop

Comment: In which case you should use `continue` or nothing at all; as it stands, the `i` is just overwritten on the next step of the loop, except when exiting the loop.

Comment: Are you looping through 70 images and wanting to save the highest pixel value from the `i`-th picture in `zeroMat(1,i)` ?

Comment: @Steve i click on the pictures by gui and than i want everytime to recevive a maximum value and finally get a matrix with maximum values

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell how this function is being invoked, so can't advice how to change up the logic. A rough fix could be to include the line

```
if ~isfield(handles,'zeroMat')
    handles.zeroMat = zeros(1,70);
end % if
```

which should create `handles.zeroMat` the first time the function is run. You could then do something like

```
firstNonzero = find(handles.zeroMat > 0, 1, 'first'); % 'first' not needed, default
handles.zeroMat(firstNonzero) = max(pic(:));
```

Comment: Error using find
Second argument must be a positive scalar integer.

Comment: @Yasmin sorry, fixed

Comment: sorry but it don't work , the output is a zeromatrix .. I will explain again- i am clicking on a picture via a list and i want for every click to get a matrix -> to get the max value -> to get a  new matrix with all the maximum values

Comment: @Yasmin maybe you could edit your question with details/code that lets us recreate your act of clicking a matrix